# Does google reject my adsense application just because i live in Lebanon?

Tags: ads, adsense

In Lebanon we don't have postal codes.

When you apply to google adsense, you have to fill your postal code. In my case, I put anything because I don't have a postal code.

Google keeps rejecting my application, some say because i live in Lebanon and Google don't want to do business with Lebanon.

But [see this](https://support.google.com/adsense/bin/answer.py?hl=en-GB&answer=62329), Google adsense Say that if i live in Lebanon, i can receive payments through western union, it's so  confusing! How can they send me money through western union, if they are not accepting my application. I have so many websites, and I am rejected on each one of them. I applied using my hubpages account and i am rejected because they say:

```
We did not approve your application for the reasons listed below.

Issues:
- Contact address incorrect, incomplete or not provided
```

Is there any Lebanese web developer on stackoverflow to tell me how is he making money from his websites?!!

Comment: You might be better off asking this question on http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/ - or, if you can't get an answer there, maybe try http://www.warriorforum.com/

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Google politics and not programming related

Answer (score 1):

No, absolutely not.

I live in Lebanon and I got my Adsense application approved.

Indeed, Google Adsense does not discriminate.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to write random postal code.Google will not use it anywhere. It is needed for post company in your country. As you don't have postal codes in your country, the letter will be transmitted to your address.